# How to force evaluation order

Tags: knockout.js

I have two computed observables that are linked together . The problem I have seem to be related to the fact that my observable are not updated in the right order ( It happens that compute is done first and then check ) which can break my application.

```js
vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.check = ko.computed(function() {
    // does some checking return true if no problem false otherwise
  };
  this.compute = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.check())
      // does computation
  }
};
```

Is there a way to force the evaluation order?

Comment: You may need to share more code.  If `compute` depends on `check`, then it will only be re-evaluated after `check` is re-evaluted.

Comment: Does self.check() forces the evalutation of check computed observable ?

Comment: Any observables/computeds that have their value accessed from within a computed's latest evaluation with become a dependency.  So, in your example, calling `self.check()` from within `compute` will create a dependency and whenever `check` is updated `compute` will get re-evaluated.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer: It does help a lot but the I need to come back to my viewmodel because there is something weird happening ( like my computed called twice ... ). I ll try to extract a simple vm that shows my problem when I have been able to spot it.

Comment: have a look at the `throttle extender`. it helped me a lot reducing the number of reevaluations. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html